# MySQL: AVG when there are no matching rows

Tags: mysql, null, average

I'm creating a website where users can rate items (say books), from 1 to 5 stars. I have created a MySQL database and a table which stores info about each rating (itemid, userid, ratingValue).

Each item has a dedicated webpage, and I'd like to put on this page info about: (1) number of ratings and (2) average rating. I thought that this was best done with a view. In thinking about MySQL queries to use in the view, I came to:

`SELECT ItemID, COUNT(ratingValue), IFNULL(AVG(ratingValue),0) FROM reviews GROUP BY ItemID`

**Problem:** if an item is not yet rated, it will not appear on the query. What I would like is that all items appear in the query result (view), and if there is an item with no reviews, it should appear with the information that there are 0 reviews and that the average rating is some arbitrary value, let's say 0.

From the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html),

> AVG() returns NULL if there were no matching rows

and for that reason I tried to use the IFNULL() function. However, it doesn't work. For example, in a database with items 1,2,3,4,5, where item 5 has no reviews, I'll get:

```
ItemID  COUNT(Rating)   IFNULL(AVG(ratingValue),0)
1           4                4.0000
2           2                4.0000
3           2                3.5000
4           3                5.0000
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have another table that lists all of your items (without regard to whether they have reviews) and left join that table to your `reviews` table. Without that, there is no way to infer from the `reviews` table alone which items may exist that have no reviews.

So something like:

```
SELECT
    i.itemID AS itemID,
    COUNT(r.rating) AS ratingCount,
    AVG(ratingValue) AS averageRating
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN reviews AS r
  ON i.itemID = r.itemID
GROUP BY i.itemID
```

This should give results like:

```
ItemID  ratingCount   averageRating
1       4             4.0000
2       2             4.0000
3       2             3.5000
4       3             5.0000
5       0             NULL
```

Comment: That worked! I never had thought of using a LEFT JOIN, but that's indeed a nice solution.